# Sorting all worksheets in a workbook at once

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

I have a workbook with 4 worksheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, ...). The sheets are the same format; the columns are identical variables, but they have different values below. So in theory, they should be able to be sorted in the same way. I've tried to ctrl-select all the tabs, but the Sort option becomes unavailable at that point.

Does anyone know if there's a way to do this without making a different macro for each of the 4 sheets? That seems annoyingly redundant. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could record a macro, then edit that code to loop through the sheets, perhaps? You'd only need one bit of code, rather than one for each sheet.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to the menu function sort.
It doesn't allow user to select cells in different worksheets and sort them.
You could implement a For each loop to sort data in each worksheet within the same macro.
Something like the following

```
Sub SortingAllWorksheet()
Dim wsh As Worksheet
For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    'sort columns A to C based on data in column C
    wsh.Columns("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("C2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Next
End Sub
```